# Different results using FindArgMax and ArgMax

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the maximum of $|g(\kappa)|$ defined as follows,

For some $A>0$, $\alpha\in (0,\infty)$, and $\kappa  \in [-\kappa^{*},\kappa^{*}]\subset [-\pi,\pi]$, define $g(\kappa )$
\begin{align}
    g(\kappa ) &= -\sqrt[]{\Big | \lambda - 4A^{2}\zeta(1+\alpha) -2(1+A^{2})\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\frac{\cos(\kappa m)}{m^{1+\alpha}} \Big |\Big ( \lambda - 2(1+A^{2})\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\frac{\cos(\kappa m)}{m^{1+\alpha}}\Big )},
\end{align}
where $\lambda = 2(1+A^{2})\zeta(1+a)$

---

With values $A = 1$ and $\alpha=3$, the following code tells me that the maximum value is achieved with $k = 3.12685$.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[k_, \[Alpha]_] := Sum[Cos[k*m]/m^(1 + \[Alpha]), {m, 1, Infinity}]
kmax = With[{A = 1, \[Alpha] = 3}, 
  N[ArgMax[{(Abs[2(1+A^2)Zeta[1+\[Alpha]]-4A^2 Zeta[1+\[Alpha]]-2(1+A^2)f[k,\[Alpha]]])(2(1+A^2)Zeta[1+\[Alpha]] - 2(1+A^2)f[k,\[Alpha]]), 0 <= k <= Pi}, k]]]
```

---

However,

```
f[k_?NumericQ, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ] := 
 Assuming[0 < k < Pi, 
  Simplify[Sum[(1 - Cos[k*m])/m^(1 + \[Alpha]), {m, 1, Infinity}]]]
data = Table[{\[Alpha], 
   First@FindArgMax[{(Abs[2(1+A^2)Zeta[1+\[Alpha]]-4A^2 Zeta[1+\[Alpha]]-2(1+A^2)f[k,\[Alpha]]])(2(1+A^2)Zeta[1+\[Alpha]] - 2(1+A^2)f[k,\[Alpha]]) /. 
       A -> 1, 0 < k <= Pi}, {k, 1}]}, {\[Alpha], 1, 9}]
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,FrameLabel -> {\[Alpha], "kmax"}]
```

tells me that for $\alpha = 3$, the corresponding "k max" would be $0.95$.

Why are these codes not coinciding in their output?

Comment: "`ArgMax` finds the global maximum of f subject to the constraints given"; whereas, `FindArgMax` "gives the position Subscript[x, max] of a local maximum of f." If the position of the local max given by `FindArgMax` is not the same as the position of a global max, provide a starting point to `FindArgMax` that starts the search near the position of a global max,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[k_, α_] := Sum[Cos[k*m]/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, Infinity}]

With[{A = 1, α = 3},
 Plot[(Abs[
     2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 4 A^2  Zeta[1 + α] - 
      2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]]) (2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 
     2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]),
  {k, 0, Pi}]]
```

[image]

```
kmax = With[{A = 1, α = 3}, 
   N[ArgMax[{(Abs[
         2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 4 A^2  Zeta[1 + α] - 
          2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]]) (2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 
         2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]), 0 <= k <= Pi}, k]]] // Quiet

(* 3.14159 *)

kmax = With[{A = 1, α = 3}, 
  FindArgMax[{(Abs[
         2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 4 A^2  Zeta[1 + α] - 
          2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]]) (2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 
         2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]), 0 <= k <= Pi}, k]][[1]]

(* 3.1415 *)
```

In this case, the default starting point for [`FindArgMax`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindArgMax.html) located the global max. However, a different starting point can return a local max.

```
kmax = With[{A = 1, α = 3}, 
  FindArgMax[{(Abs[
         2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 4 A^2  Zeta[1 + α] - 
          2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]]) (2 (1 + A^2) Zeta[1 + α] - 
         2 (1 + A^2) f[k, α]), 0 <= k <= Pi}, {k, 1}]][[1]]

(* 0.956882 *)
```

Comment: In the syntax, where do you specify a starting point?

Comment: As shown in the documentation, "FindArgMax[f, {x, Subscript[x, 0]}] gives the position Subscript[x, max] of a local maximum of f, found by a search starting from the point x = Subscript[x, 0]. "